# BigQuery performance impact with column data length

Tags: google-bigquery, spring-cloud-gcp-bigquery

Problem statement -

We are planning to store hexadecimal string data with length 64 in a BigQuery column. Will it affect the BigQuery query performance when queries are run with filter/join operations on these columns (with large string lengths) compared to when a smaller length string is stored?

Example -

> Let's assume there is a BigQuery table - `abc.HACKERNEWS.news`
>
> Columns -
>
> `id`, `time`, `time_ts`, `encrypted_data`, `news`, `status`.
>
> Known - `encrypted_data` column has String with length 32.
>
> Query -
> `SELECT time FROM abc.HackerNews.news where encrypted_data = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123deabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde' LIMIT 1000`
>
> How will the performance impact with the change encrypted_data length?
> Will the query perform better if the length of the string length
> stored in encrypted_data column is shorter say 5?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [this documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data) in regards to data size calculation:

*STRING (data types are equal to) 2 bytes + the UTF-8 encoded string size*

So answering your question: yes, the longer the string, the more bytes the query will need to process, and the slower it will be. Therefore, choosing a shorter string length might improve the query performance.